# XPath to select an element after some marker (but before the next marker or the end)

Tags: xpath, predicate

I'm trying to screen-scrape links from a table that looks like this:

```
…
<table id="t">
  <tr><td>Section 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="some_link?for=one">View Report</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Section 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>No report for section three</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Section 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Nothing for section four either.</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Section 4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="some_link?for=four">View Report</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Some content</td></tr>
</table>
…
```

There are three sections, but they are represented linearly rather than hierarchically in the table.  Each section may have zero or one link whose text is "View Report".

What is an XPath that I can use to select the `<a>` element corresponding to Section *n* (or an empty collection if no such element exists)?

As a first cut, I've considered

```
//table[@id='t']/tr[td='Section %d']/following-sibling::tr/td/a['View Report'][1]
```

(where `%d` is a placeholder for *n*).  However, that would falsely select the last link for *n* = 2.

I could also try

```
//table[@id='t']/tr[td='Section %d']/following-sibling::tr[following-sibling::tr/td='Section %d']/td/a['View Report'][1]
```

with two `%d` placeholders for *n* and *n* + 1, respectively, but that won't work for the last section.  Furthermore, requiring two interpolations is inelegant.  Is there a good solution that handles all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it backwards: find the link where the preceding "Section Anything" is the "Section" you are looking for.

```
//a["View Report"][../../preceding-sibling::tr[td[contains(.,"Section")]][1][.="Section 3"]]/@href
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what should be returned in case there is no `<a>` element corresponding to the section in question, but following xpath won't return a match in case the `<a>` element has a preceding section with a value higher than the section in question - for n = 2:

```
//table[@id='t']/tr[td='Section 2']/following-sibling::tr/td[
  not(./parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[
       normalize-space(translate(td,'Section',''))>2])
       ]/a['View Report'][1]
```

for n:

```
//table[@id='t']/tr[td='Section n']/following-sibling::tr/td[
  not(./parent::tr/preceding-sibling::tr[
      normalize-space(translate(td,'Section',''))>n])
      ]/a['View Report'][1]
```